# react antd notification renders only after i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I don't know why notification shows only after refreshing the page. Maybe somebody faced it

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const handleSave = async () => {
    // ... other code

    try {
      await axios.put(...);
      // success handling
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === "ERR_BAD_REQUEST") {
        //
      } else {
        // handle generic error
        notification.error({
            message: t("Error while saving"),
            description: JSON.stringify(error.response.data),
            placement: "topRight",
            duration: 2,
        })
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    // ... Other component content
  );
};
```

Expect notification error to show without refreshing

Comment: Please provide the code of where and how you use `handleSave ` function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.